# Django: How to get an object from many to many field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I am creating digital products for my eCommerce application.

I have created a model Product_activation to activate particular product whenever the user is subscribed to the product

I have done the following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   full_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
   name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)
   subscribed_products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='products_subscribed',blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
   title        = models.CharField(max_length=32)
   price        = models.DecimalField(default=10000.00,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

class Product_activation(models.Model):
   user         = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
   product     = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='product_activate')
   activate    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have created this below signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def product_activation(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    if instance.subscribed_products:
        Product_activation.objects.update_or_create(
            User=instance.name,
            product=instance.subscribed_products,
            activate=False,
            deactivate=True
        )
```

But having problem in `product=instance.subscribed_products` line of code.

This is giving me the following error message:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my code?

Thank you

Comment: `product=instance.subscribed_products` --> `product=instance.subscribed_products.all()`

Comment: and looks like a typo `instance.Name` should be in lowcase `instance.name`

Comment: Just a remark regarding the naming conventions. Please follow the style guide provided by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Don't use `snake_case` for class names, use `ProductActivation` instead of `Product_activation`. Use `snake_case` for class attributes, for example `full_name` instead of `full_Name`. Use verbs for methods, not for attributes, `activate` should be rather `is_active`. By the way it's very confusing to have `activate` and `deactivate` as attributes. What will you do if both values are `False`?

Comment: and please read a little here [coding-style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

Comment: Yeah I have specific views for that...@cezar

Comment: @Bear Brown If I use `product=instance.subscribed_products.all()` I am getting an error `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.`...As because the field is a foreign key field...

Comment: and what product do you want single or all? if single what is the rule to find it?

Comment: @BearBrown Regarding your first comment you're right. The error message is caused by that part. However `instance.subscribed_products.all()` returns a `QuerySet`, yet `product` is a `ForeignKey` to `Product` and would expect either an integer or `Product` object.

Comment: @NiladryKar You have to pass a single `Product` object to `product` in the mentioned line. You can't pass a `QuerySet` of all `subscribed_products`.

Comment: @cezar thats what I am asking for that is my exact query as the instance of my signal is `Profile`..So what should I pass in `product=instance.subscribed_products` to get the product that the user has subscribed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on all comments:

first read the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [Django coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/).

To fix your current error you can use the method `all` of the `ManyRelatedManager`, for example it can look like:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def product_activation(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    for product in instance.subscribed_products.all():
        Product_activation.objects.update_or_create(
            User=instance.name, product=product, activate=False, deactivate=True
        )
```